# How to smoothen the data into stepped curve?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a saved data frame for which I got local maxima and local minima calculated. refer attached picture- [data frame plot with local minima and maxima](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xWJ9n.png).
In this pic, I combined the local minima and maxima column into single and then filled all NAN with zeros hence at zero we see a lot of red dots. below code I used for this purpose:

```
n=10
df['min'] = df.iloc[argrelextrema(df.data.values, np.less_equal,
                order=n)[0]]['data']
df['max'] = df.iloc[argrelextrema(df.data.values, np.greater_equal,
                order=n)[0]]['data']
df['min'].fillna(0, inplace=True)
df['max'].fillna(0, inplace=True)
df['min_max'] = df['min']+df['max']
```

My objective is to convert this local minima and maxima data into something like a step curve, as shown in this [required output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JYp7G.png).

Also, there is one more issue which is shown in [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gH7vp.png) as pointed by arrows, I have no idea, how to deal with them.

Any hint will be good for me, I can code based on that...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**zero** is not correct value for `fillna()`.  It's better as the local minimum or maximum

- generated a curve off *sine* curve and randomised it to give it a few features
- calculated local min/max as per method you have used
- `fillna(method="bfill", limit=n//3)` to replicate min / max backwards.  Similarly for forwards
- most graphing libraries (used **seaborn**) skip `nan` which is wanted behaviour

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.signal import argrelextrema
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import seaborn as sns

# randomize a sine curve a bit...
df = pd.DataFrame(np.sin([a/(2*np.pi) for a in range(180)])*np.random.choice([1,.8,1.2],180, p=(.5,.25,.25)), columns=["data"])

n=10
df['min'] = df.iloc[argrelextrema(df.data.values, np.less_equal,
                order=n)[0]]['data']
df['max'] = df.iloc[argrelextrema(df.data.values, np.greater_equal,
                order=n)[0]]['data']
# combine local minima and maxima
df["min_max"] = np.select([~df["min"].isna(),~df["max"].isna()], [df["min"],df["max"]], np.nan)
# backfill and forward fill for desired outcome on graph...
df["min_max"] = df["min_max"].fillna(method="bfill",limit=n//3).fillna(method="ffill", limit=n//3)

# plot it...
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1,1,figsize=(14, 3))
sns.lineplot(data=df.loc[:,["data","min_max"]], ax=ax)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, @RobRaymond for the code, I have one issue with it and that is, df["min_max"] contains NaN which is to be filled for in-between inclined line values. One way I can think is to fit a line between all those points, but I guess that will consume a lot of time, any suggestion?

Comment: if you want to do interpolation yourself you can... `df["min_max_i"] = df["min_max"].interpolate()`  **min_max_i** will contain no NaN...

Comment: Thank you, @Rib Raymond, It's not like I want to do that, rather I am thinking that could be one way to fill those NaN for the inclined line. If there is any other easy and fast way please suggest.

Comment: it's not expensive, as you can see seaborn is doing it anyway.  almost all graphing libraries have capabilities to interpolate missing values.  you can choose to do it yourself (panda interpolate) or delegate it to graphing library